# Press submit button in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I'm trying to hit the Go button here:
`http://ideal-scope.com/online-holloway-cut-adviser/`
I've already started RSelenium...

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
pJS <- phantom()
Sys.sleep(5) # give the binary a moment
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
remDr$open()
```

...accessed the enclosing iFrame...

```
remDr$navigate("http://ideal-scope.com/online-holloway-cut-adviser/")
Sys.sleep(5)
webElems <- remDr$findElements("css", "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(webElems[[1]])
```

...and extracted the button.

```
 subElem   <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//input[@type="submit"]')
```

but when I try either

```
subElem$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
subElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "space"))
```

Nothing happens.
I know I have access to the page otherwise, since I've changed the values in those input boxes successfully. example:

```
depthElem <- remDr$findElement("name","depth_textbox")
depthElem$clearElement()
depthElem$sendKeysToElement(list(diamondsDT[theRow]$DepthPct))
```

Right now I'm checking `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html` to view the webpage. After the press attempt, nothing changes, but I can still see my updated values in the boxes.

Comment: The `webElement` class has a `clickElement` method. `subElem$clickElement()`.

Comment: YES!
answer for credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `RSelenium` you can `POST` the form withing the *iframe* directly. You just need to set the referer header as follows:

```
require(httr)
require(rvest)

q <- list(
  depth_textbox = 60,
  table_textbox = 57,
  crown_listbox = 0,
  crown_textbox = 34,
  pavilion_listbox = 0,
  pavilion_textbox = 40.5,
  cutlet_textbox = 0
)

my_url <- "http://www.pricescope.com/hca.php" # url of the iframe:
doc <- POST(my_url,
          body = q, encode = "form",
          # THIS IS THE CRUTIAL LINE
          add_headers(Referer = "http://ideal-scope.com/online-holloway-cut-adviser/")) %>% 
  read_html
```

Now doc is the *iframe*-content after you have submitted the form.
If you would like to extract the img and plot it you could do this:

```
img_url <- doc %>% html_nodes("img") %>% html_attr("src") %>% .[[2]]
tmp_file <- tempfile()
GET(xml2::url_absolute(img_url, my_url), write_disk(tmp_file))
#install.packages("ReadImages")
library('ReadImages')
plot(1:2, type="n")
rasterImage(readJPEG(tmp_file), 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Nice! the graph at the bottom is missing the you-are-here "X" though. This is a separate element not in the image.